# How to call a console app as a different user, using a Windows service being run under Local System?

Tags: c#, .net, command-line, windows-services, console-application

I am basically trying to create and run a Windows Service on a server. This service has mainly 2 jobs,

1. To log a timestamp to a file on a UNC (different Server path) so as to check access
2. Call a simple console app using a different user

Now, I have created the windows service, but it won't log in the Server path as it is started via Local system. So I tried to deploy it using a user account with access to the Server Path and it logged, but then the whole point is to us the local system.

So now, i changed the requirement a little bit, Now is it possible to deploy the service as Local System only , but instead of directly logging on the server path, i would rather make the console app do the logging. But how should I make the console app run as a different user account.

This is the code I am using for calling the console app via a different user (mind you the service is run under LocalSystem), and it is either giving the error, "Cannot find the file specified" or "Invalid Directory Name" but i assure you both the things exist. I even used the paths fed in the startInfo by debugging to check.

```
public static void InitiateCommandProcess()
    {            
        Process process = new Process();
        SecureString ssPwd = new SecureString();
        string fileName = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["FileName"];
        string workingDirectory = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ApplicationDirectory"];
        string param = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["PARAM"];            
        string userName = "myUserName";
        string password = "MyPassWord";            

        for (int x = 0; x < password.Length; x++)
        {
            ssPwd.AppendChar(password[x]);
        }

        ProcessStartInfo startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo
        {
            UseShellExecute = false,
            WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden,
            CreateNoWindow = true,
            ErrorDialog = false,
            FileName = @"" + fileName,
            WorkingDirectory = @"" + workingDirectory,                
            Arguments = @"" + param,
            RedirectStandardOutput = true,
            RedirectStandardError = true,
            RedirectStandardInput = true,
            Domain = "EMEA",
            UserName = userName,
            Password = ssPwd                
        };

        process.StartInfo = startInfo;
        try
        {
            Logger.Log($"Working in Directory Path : {workingDirectory} );");
            Logger.Log($" Username : {userName} and Executing : {fileName}");
            process.Start();
            Logger.Log($"Process \"{ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["FileName"]}\" Executed at {DateTime.Now}");
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Logger.Log($"Error occured in command process execution, Message : {ex.Message}", true);
        }
    }
```

The server path is like this, "\dfs\folder\folder..."

I am a little new to this so please bear with me.

Comment: Either `NetworkService` or `LocalSystem` should work, provided that the permissions on that remote path allow access for this machine's *computer* account.